# How to disable gesture swipe for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swipe, gesture, uipagecontrol

Currently, I'm making paging UICollectionView. I want to disable gesture swipe effect from UICollectionView as I'm going to add UIPagerControl to animate the paging UICollectionView. I don't want user uses their finger to move to next screen instead of using custom UIPageControl.

Answer (score 7):

A UICollection inherits from UIScrollView and the user's scrolling can be disable this way:

```
myCollectionView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Here is the documentation explanation ([UIScrollView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollEnabled)):

> When scrolling is disabled, the scroll view does not accept touch
>   events; it forwards them up the responder chain.

When using your UIPageControl, you can programmatically set the position in your UICollectionView using the UIScrollView method:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset
                animated:(BOOL)animated
```